# Going through a DataReader twice

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5

I have the following code which does what it's supposed to do:

```
objSQLCommand = New SqlCommand("select * from table1", objSQLConnection)

objSQLCommand.Connection.Open()
objSQLDataReader = objSQLCommand.ExecuteReader()

While objSQLDataReader.Read()
    objStringBuilder.Append(objSQLDataReader("forename"))
    objStringBuilder.Append("<br /><br />")
    objStringBuilder.Append(objSQLDataReader("surname"))
    objStringBuilder.Append("<br /><br />")
End While

objSQLDataReader.Close()
objSQLCommand.Connection.Close()
```

But I need to loop through the objSQLDataReader 1 more time.  How would I do that?

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot do what you need to do on the second iteration at the same time as doing the first?

Comment: @adrianbanks: On the first iteration, I want the html to have certain structure, on the second iteration I want the html to have another structure.  The first structure ontop of the second.

Comment: DataReader is forward only, is there a reason you cannot do whatever you need in one interation?

Comment: @HadleyHope: On the first iteration, I want the html to have certain structure, on the second iteration I want the html to have another structure. The first structure ontop of the second.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Three options:

- execute the query twice (readers like this are forwards only)
- buffer the data locally, *then* process it twice (the "buffer" could be an object collection, XML, a DataTable (spit), etc)
- write both outputs **at the same time**; i.e. for each row, write the first format to the first output, then the second format to the second output

I'd probably aim at the last option, as it involves no buffering or repetition; however I would move the logic for each method into 2 distinct methods

Comment: Or consider using a DataSet and DataTable.Rows http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows.aspx

Comment: @Hadley I actually added that already when clarifying "buffering". But I still don't like them much :)

Comment: In my case, I just put them in a generic collection of a type in my EF, then iterate over them again when I need to.

Answer (score 4):

Loop through data reader only once and load your data into some sort of an instantiated collection (e.g. `List<MyDataObject>`) that you can reference later to loop through again and again, and again.